# Weighted bipartite graph clustering in R

Tags: r, module, cluster-analysis, bipartite

I've a weighted bipartite graph such as :

```
A   V   5
A   W   4
A   X   1
B   V   5
B   W   6
C   V   7
C   W   4
D   W   2
D   X   5
D   Z   7
E   X   4
E   Y   5
E   Z   8
```

[image]

```
structure(list(g1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", 
"D", "D", "E", "E", "E"), g2 = c("V", "W", "X", "V", "W", "V", 
"W", "W", "X", "Z", "X", "Y", "Z"), w = c(5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Is there a clustering approach to detect highly connected nodes between group 1 and 2. For instance in the example above two clustering seems to exists :

```
A,B,C - V,W
D,E - X,Y,Z
```

I found this function from the bipartite package : https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bipartite/versions/2.11/topics/computeModules  . However I would like to have some kind of p-value or score for each cluster telling me its "robustness". Any idea ?

```
m <- as_adjacency_matrix(graph_from_data_frame(g),attr = "w") %>% 
       as.matrix() %>% 
       computeModules()    
listModuleInformation(m)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"

[[1]][[1]][[2]]
[1] "V" "W" "X" "Z" "Y"



[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[[2]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C"

[[2]][[1]][[2]]
[1] "V" "W"


[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]][[1]]
[1] "D" "E"

[[2]][[2]][[2]]
[1] "X" "Z" "Y"
```

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: Do you have an example of how each cluster would be assigned a measure of robustness? From what I've seen, most assign numbers to a clustering as a whole (so you can compare different ways in which the vertices can be clustered and choose the best one) not to individual clusters. Though you could come up with your own measure (e.g. (#edges within cluster)/(#edges outside of cluster)) but I'm not sure if that would be an answer to your question.

Comment: Can you please include code to reproduce the graph?

Comment: One simple measure of robustness could be found by removing 1, 2 up to k edges, and seeing how many permutations where 1 to k edges affect the clusters. Letting i be the number of removed edges, a -sorta- p value for robustness, could be calculated as the number of permutations for which the underlying clusters over the total number of permutations. This could be calculated explicitly, or by bootstrapping.

Comment: I think the answer is a.) mostly statistical and b.) a bit application specific because a robustness measure or a p-value depends on the null hypothesis or comparison. You could (for instance) hypothesize h0: the network is a random graph with constant linking probability p and simulate the distribution of the clustering algorithm under the null by generating random edges and then answer questions like 'what is the probability of finding k clusters when there are none', or 'what is the probability nodes i and j share a cluster when there is no clustering structure to the graph'.

Comment: @Oliver deleting edges is an interesting approach but its unclear to me what it would be testing, apart from the robustness of the clusters to observational measurement error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using the clustering coefficient by Watts/Strogatz (also called "transitivity")? It measures the tendency of a node's neigbours to be connected to each other. You could compute the clustering coefficients for all the nodes in your network and then average among the nodes in each cluster. The result would indicate how close a cluster is to a cliqe, i.e. a completely connected subgraph.

Transitivity is implemented in the igraph package.

See also the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient) page for generalizations for weighted networks.